# There are duplicate viewreset events when loading different path features in Leaflet with D3.js

Tags: d3.js, leaflet

I'm using D3js with leaflet (similar to the http://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/).

But when I load different path feature into the svg, I got duplicate viewreset events after each time.
Like I first load the US states data, I got single viewreset event when I zoom in/out.
But after I load the US county data, I got two viewreset events when i zoom in/out.
And when I switch again, I even got more viewreset events.

Should it be one viewreset event, when I zoom in/out once?

Comment: Are you running `map.on("viewreset", reset);` every time you add new data? You should only run it once.

Comment: I'm using map.on("viewreset", function(e){ console.log("viewreset"); }); And I can see that when I zoom in once, but I get multiple "viewreset" somehow.

Comment: You need to run this code exactly once, not every time you're loading data.

Comment: Will add this as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call the code to attach a handler to the `viewreset` event, a new handler is attached. That is, you end up with several (identical) handlers that are all executed if you run the code every time you load new data.

The solution is to run the code that attaches the handler exactly once.